# allowEmptyString() - Means allow only an empty string or a populated string and an empty string

Tags: cakephp

CakePHP Version: 4.0.1

**// Introduction**

I need to validate my grade select list so it accepts an empty string or a populated string.

---

I'd like to check my interpretation of the following sentence which can be found [here](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/core-libraries/validation.html#allowing-empty-fields).

> allowEmptyString() Should be used when you want to only accept an
>   empty string.

Does this mean I should only use this function when I **ONLY** want to accept an empty string or when I want to accept an empty string or a populated string.

The reason I'm asking is because when I use allowEmptyString() it negates the displaying of --Select-- in my select lists. Please see below:

**// Markets Add View**

```
$options = [
    '' => '--Select--', // THIS IS WHAT IS NOT DISPLAYED WHEN I USE allowEmptyString() IN THE MARKETS TABLE VALIDATOR.
    'A' => 'A',
    'B' => 'B',
    'C' => 'C',
    'D' => 'D',
    'E' => 'E'
];

echo $this->Form->control('grade', [
    'type' => 'select',
    'options' => $options,
    'class' => 'ns-std std',
    'autocomplete' => 'off',
    'label' => false
]);
```

**// Markets table default validator**

```
->scalar('grade')
->allowEmptyString('grade') // IF I COMMENT THIS LINE THE --Select-- OPTION IS DISPLAYED.
->add('grade', 'validGrade', [
    'rule' => 'isValidGrade',
    'message' => __('Invalid grade!'),
    'provider' => 'table'
])
```

---

If I make a literal interpretation of the sentence it means to me that I should NOT use this function in the validator because the grade select list can except a populated string OR an empty string and the sentence reads 'only accept an empty string'

But before I go ahead and delete all references to allowEmptyString() in my validators where appropriate I thought I'd check.

Also by default this would mean that there is no check for a empty or populated string.

---

**// My Question**

Is my interpretation of the sentence correct and I should NOT use this function because I want to accept an empty OR a populated string.

Thanks Zenzs.

---

**EDIT** Salines...

**// Markets Add View**

```
echo $this->Form->select(
    'grade',
    ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
    [
       'empty' => '--Select--',
       'class' => 'ns-std std',
       'autocomplete' => 'off',
       'label' => false
    ],
 );
```

**// Markets table default validator**

```
->scalar('grade')
->allowEmptyString('grade')
```

The above method all works and I now validate successfully for an empty string and a populated string.

I'll have to create a new `custom validation rule` as 0, 1, 2, 3 and 4 instead of A, B, C, D and E are inserted into the database and a cell to handle the conversions in the view but that's no problem. I'll have to do that tommorrow though as I've run out of time today.

Comment: https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/views/helpers/form.html#options-for-select-checkbox-and-radio-controls

Comment: What the sentence means is that it will allow empty inputs if they are strings, but not otherwise; empty dates, arrays, etc. will be rejected.